# Non Root User request to root for a specific service restart

Tags: linux, security, sudo, root

We have a typical problem in our environment.
Typically we have users with non SUDOER and ROOT access who are monitoring services of our application.

At times they need to restart a service which only ROOT user can do it.

For example : The team member sees that certain service needs to be restarted after changes in the database.

From security point of view, we do not want to give them SUDO access.

What other options do we have?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the service you want to be managed by regular user to sudoers file:

Adding commonads in sudoers:

https://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/

example command:

```
<your-user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start program.service
```